# How to specify bins in the Histogram which are right closed and left open except for the first one?

Tags: histograms

Consider the following data as an example:

```
data={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

Histogram[data,{1,9,2}]
```

This produces the following histogram:

[image]

This has done left closed right open. I know distribution functions are supposed to be right continuous so this is consistent. But I want to match the output of Excel.

[image]

Here the bins are left open but right closed. And the first one is closed on both ends.
What is the simplest way to define these bins?

Comment: A "hack" I can think of is to add a small amount to your bin size. E.g. `Histogram[data, {1, 9, 2 + 10^-10}]`. That doesn't change the open-closed-ness of the boundaries, but it reproduces the desired chart.

Answer (score 1):

```
dat = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
histopenclose[dat_] := 
 Histogram[
  dat - Prepend[ConstantArray[10^-12, Length[dat] - 1], 0], {1, 9, 2}]
histopenclose[dat]
```

[image]